# Parse xml and remove width attribute from Image Tag

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading an XML file and parsing it. I want to remove the `width` attribute from every `img` element that is part of the XML document.

How do I parse this HTML file and search for the image tag and update it and return that updated HTML?

Follow  is XML sample ..In description tag want to remove img attr

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
>

  <channel>
<title></title>
<atom:link href="" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
<link></link>
<description>Award-Winning Impact Media - Alt Protein &#38; 
    Sustainability Breaking News</description>
<lastBuildDate>Sun, 24 Oct 2021 19:27:36 +0000</lastBuildDate>
<language>en-US</language>
<sy:updatePeriod>
hourly  </sy:updatePeriod>
<sy:updateFrequency>
1   </sy:updateFrequency>

<item>
    <title>Vegan .</title>
    <link>https://www.google.com</link>
    
    <dc:creator><![CDATA[Sally Ho]]></dc:creator>
    <pubDate>Mon, 25 Oct 2021 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
            <category><![CDATA[Alt Protein]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[Seafood]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[Vegan]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[alternative seafood]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[plant based tuna]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[vegan seafood]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[vegan tuna]]></category>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">https://www.google.com/?p=55401</guid>

                <description><![CDATA[<div style="margin- 
 bottom:20px;"> 
<img width="1024" height="768" src="" class="attachment-post- 
  thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="" 
  sizes=" 
    (max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px" /></div>
     <p><span class="rt-reading-time" style="display: block;"><span 
     class="rt-label rt-prefix"></span> <span class="rt- 
       time">4</span> 
       <span class="rt-label rt-postfix">  Mins Read</span></span> 
      </p>
     <p>The post <a rel="nofollow" 
       href="https://www.greenqueen.com.hk/vegan-tuna-brands/"> <a 
      rel="nofollow" href="">Green</a>.</p>
    ]]></description>
    </item>
```

Comment: Do you need the procedure to return *text* or an object like a parse tree? Do you need to remove the `width` attribute from *every* image tag? What constitutes an "image tag" -- the HTML `img` element?

Comment: yes want to remove the width attribute from  every img tag

Comment: From *all* image tags?

Comment: yes from all img tag

Comment: You're inconsistent - are you talking about XML or about HTML?

Comment: How are you parsing the file?

Comment: its XML ... for parsing XML i'm using rss-parser

Comment: Do you have any sample XML you are parsing ?

Comment: adding sample XML in question please NOTE its just  a sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` will not work in this case because the html is contained in a CDATA (character data) section. The contents of these sections are not parsed by the XML parser and not considered as markup.

See W3C reference:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect
- https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-chardata

If they contain HTML, the easiest way to manipulate them in vanilla javascript is to read the content from the `nodeValue` property and set it as the `innerHTML` property of a temporary element appended to a new [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment). This gives you the ability to use the methods normally found in `document` to search for elements using selectors. (`removeWidthFromCDATA` function on the snippet below).

```js
const xmlStr = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0"
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
>

  <channel>
<title></title>
<atom:link href="" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
<link></link>
<description>Award-Winning Impact Media - Alt Protein &#38; 
    Sustainability Breaking News</description>
<lastBuildDate>Sun, 24 Oct 2021 19:27:36 +0000</lastBuildDate>
<language>en-US</language>
<sy:updatePeriod>
hourly  </sy:updatePeriod>
<sy:updateFrequency>
1   </sy:updateFrequency>

<item>
    <title>Vegan .</title>
    <link>https://www.google.com</link>
    
    <dc:creator><![CDATA[Sally Ho]]></dc:creator>
    <pubDate>Mon, 25 Oct 2021 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
            <category><![CDATA[Alt Protein]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[Seafood]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[Vegan]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[alternative seafood]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[plant based tuna]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[vegan seafood]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[vegan tuna]]></category>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">https://www.google.com/?p=55401</guid>

                <description><![CDATA[<div style="margin- 
 bottom:20px;"> 
<img width="1024" height="768" src="" class="attachment-post- 
  thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="" 
  sizes=" 
    (max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px" /></div>
     <p><span class="rt-reading-time" style="display: block;"><span 
     class="rt-label rt-prefix"></span> <span class="rt- 
       time">4</span> 
       <span class="rt-label rt-postfix">  Mins Read</span></span> 
      </p>
     <p>The post <a rel="nofollow" 
       href="https://www.greenqueen.com.hk/vegan-tuna-brands/"> <a 
      rel="nofollow" href="">Green</a>.</p>
    ]]></description>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>`;

function removeWidthFromCDATA(cdataString) {
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    const html = document.createElement("div");
    html.innerHTML = cdataString;
    fragment.appendChild(html);
    
    const images = fragment.querySelectorAll("img");

    for (const image of images)
        if (image.hasAttribute("width"))
            image.removeAttribute("width");

    return html.innerHTML;
}

function cleanRSS(xmlString) {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "application/xml");
    const errorNode = doc.querySelector("parsererror");
    if (errorNode) {
        console.error("Error parsing xml string.")
        return false;
    }

    const descs = doc.querySelectorAll("description");
    for (const desc of descs) {
        let content = desc.firstChild;
        if (!content || content.nodeType !== Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE)
            continue;

        content.nodeValue = removeWidthFromCDATA(content.nodeValue);
    }

    const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    return serializer.serializeToString(doc);
}

console.log(cleanRSS(xmlStr));
```

As a side note: pay attention to the template you use to generate the RSS feed. If you have control, you need to fix **the missing closing of the `<a>` tag** at the end and pay attention to the **spaces before the newlines** because they interrupt the names of the CSS classes and properties applied to the elements inside the CDATA section.

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide sample input and output, we can extend this snippet and make it runnable.

```js
// `xml` is the xml document
const imgs = xml.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (const img of imgs) {
  if (img.hasAttribute("width")) {
    img.removeAttribute("width");
  }
}
// output xml/html string from `xml`
```

Comment: Already tried this solution but not worked

Comment: Mind if posting your data and error message here?